# Iterating JSON array using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I have a JSON array ( partial data).

```
   {
      "person1": { "firstName":  "Joe", "lastName":"Dutonz"},
      "person2": { "firstName":  "Joe", "lastName":"Foo"},
etc
    }
```

The requirement is to loop through the JSON array and display all the firstName of the people data.

```
$.getJSON("people.json", function(obj)
 {
    loop through people data and display firstName
});
```

Using jQuery how to fetch firstName?

Comment: It does not looks like an array.

Comment: @SubirKumarSao ..not just looks like.. it is **not an array** at all...

Comment: @Subir , I have already  mentioned that it is a partial data

Comment: Can you show at least two elements? Is it an array of objects or just a single object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what the `for` iterator was designed for e.g.

```
$.getJSON("people.json", function(obj)
{
    for (var propName in obj)
    {
        console.log(obj[propName]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.each()` function to loop through the key value pairs and display the value as shown below.

```
$.getJSON("people.json", function(obj){   
     $.each(obj, function(key,value){
         alert(value.firstName);
     });
});
```